# ¿Cual es la forma correcta de cargar en un table datos recuperados con Spring, Hibernate y JQuery?

Tags: java, jquery, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc

estoy trabajando con Spring mvc, hibernate con con conexion a SQL y tengo problema al cargar datos en un table mo que tengo es lo siguiente.

Pojo:

```
public class Trabajador implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String idTrabajador;
    private EstadoTrabajador estadoTrabajador;
    private FormaPago formaPago;
    private Nacionalidad nacionalidad;
    private Periocidad periocidad;
    private Persona persona;
    private Sucursal sucursal;
    private TipoTrabajador tipoTrabajador;
 //getter and setter
}
```

Mi dao:

```
@Override
    public List<Trabajador> findAll() {
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        List result = null;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Trabajador T");
            result = query.list();
            tx.commit();
        }catch(HibernateException he ){
            if(tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        }finally{
            session.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Mi controlador:

```
@Controller
public class TrabajadoresController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/empleados", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String vistaEmpleados() {
        System.err.println("Entro a TrabajadoresController");
        return "rrhh/empleados";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/trabajadores", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> getAllEmployes() {
        System.out.println("getAllEmployes de TrabajadoresController:");
        STrabajador st = new STrabajador();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<Trabajador> list = st.listarTrabajadores() ? st.getLTrabajador() : new ArrayList<>();
        map.put("status", 200);
        map.put("message", "Datos encontrados");
        map.put("data", list);
        System.err.println("Entro a lista y contiene " +list.size()+ " datos");
        return map;
    }
}
```

Lugar donde cargare los datos:

```
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <!-- LISTA DE TRABAJADORES -->
                            <div id="lista-empleados" class="tab-pane fade in active "  style="padding-top: 30px;">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            cargarTrabajadores();
                        });
                    </script>
```

y por ultimo ajax:

```
function cargarTrabajadores() {
    var table =
            '<table id="tbl-trabajador" class="table-trabajador table table-striped responsive-utilities jambo_table">' +
            '<thead>' +
            '<tr class="headings">' +
            '<th class="hidden"></th>' +
            '<th>DNI</th>' +
            '<th>Apellidos y Nombres</th>' +
            '<th>Teléfono</th>' +
            '<th>Dirección</th>' +
            '<th>Tipo</th>' +
            '<th>Estado</th>' +
            '<th class=" no-link last"> <span>  Acciones  </span> </th>' +
            '</tr>' +
            '</thead>' +
            '<tbody>';
    alert("cargarTrabajadores");

    $.ajax({
        url: "trabajadores.htm",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (responseText) {
            data = responseText.data;
            if (data !== null) {
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    table = table +
                            '<tr class="odd pointer">' +
                            '<td class="hidden">' + JSON.stringify(item) + '</td>' +
                            '<td class=" ">' + item.dni + '</td>' +
                            '<td class=" ">' + item.ap_paterno + ' ' + item.ap_materno + ' ' + item.nombres + '</td>' +
                            '<td class="a-right a-right ">' + item.telefono + '</td>' +
                            '<td class=" ">' + item.direccion + '</td>' +
                            '<td class=" ">' + item.tipoTrabajador.descripcion + '</td>' +
                            '<td class="text-center">' +
                            '<span class="label ' + item.estadoTrabajador.descripcion + ' "> ' + item.estadoTrabajador.descripcion + '</span>' +
                            '</td>' +
                            '<td class=" a-center ">' +
                            '<a style="cursor: pointer;" class="btn-trabajador-info btn btn-info btn-xs"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#panel-info" title="Información"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>' +
                            '<a style="cursor: pointer;" class="btn-trabajador-edit btn btn-dark btn-xs"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#panel-trabajador" title="Editar"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>';
                    if (item.nro_hijos > 0) {
                        table = table +
                                '<a style="cursor: pointer;" class="btn-trabajador-hijo btn btn-primary btn-xs"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#panel-hijos" title="Hijos"><i class="fa fa-child"></i></a>';
                    }
                    table = table + '</td> </tr>';
                });
            }
            table = table + '</tbody> </table>';

            $("#lista-empleados").html(table);
            inicializaTabla($("#tbl-trabajador"));
        }
    });

    alert("termino");
}
```

pero al final no se cargan los datos, no me muestra ningún erro. Alguien tiene idea de que puede ser?

Comment: ¿Qué muestra el `System.err.println(list.size())`?

Comment: 17, esto es la cantidad de datos.

Comment: ¿Lo pudiste resolver? Itinera sobre la lista en el controlador. Creo que el problema va a estar en el JS. Aparte, ¿No se requiere otro `@ResponseBody` arriba del parámetro? Creo que tendría que llevar dos, pero no estoy seguro.

Comment: Aun no lo soluciono, también estoy intentando mostrar un objeto en json en mi navegador utilizando las librerías jackson (bind,core,annotations) sin embargo me sale el mensaje (HTTP Status 406 - Not Acceptable)